# how to set focus on a custom combo box using jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]    im trying to set focus on a custom combo box,which doesn't have id,How to set focus to a custom combo box shown in the picture

i'm using below code but it's not working

```
$('.custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left selectOuterformleft ui-autocomplete-input').focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the classes

```
$('.custom-combobox-input.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-state-default.ui-corner-left.selectOuterformleft.ui-autocomplete-input').focus();
```